# How canvas tag is beneficial in HTML5?

Tags: html

I am a junior developer I can't understand how canvas tag is beneficial for us?
I read lot of articles on that but I can't get the root benefit getting from the canvas tag.

Comment: I presume you're not asking for more descriptions about what it does or how to use it, as that sounds like what you've been reading already.  Are you asking for concrete use-cases that help to explain (justify?) why the `canvas` tag was added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of the difference between canvas and svg as the difference betwee Photoshop and Illustrator (or Gimp and Inkscape for you OSS folks). One deals with bitmaps and the other vector art.

With canvas, since you are drawing in bitmap, you can smudge, blur, burn, dodge your images easily. But since it's bitmap you can't easily draw a line and then decide to reposition the line. You need to delete the old line and then draw a new line.

With svg, since you are drawing vectors, you can easily move, scale, rotate, reposition, flip your drawings. But since it's vectors you can't easily blur the edges according to line thickness or seamlessly meld a red circle into a blue square. You need to simulate blurring by  drawing intermediate polygons between objects.

Sometimes their use case overlaps. Like a lot of people use canvas to do simple line drawings and keep track of the objects as data structures in javascript. But really, they both serve different purposes. If you try to implement general purpose vector drawing in pure javascript on top of canvas I doubt you'd be faster than using svg which is most likely implemented in C.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, thanks to canvas, we can now draw/render 2D shapes using HTML5 and the canvas API.

As an example of what's possible now with canvas, [see this](http://muro.deviantart.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Some possible uses for Canvas:

- Image drawing program
- Photo editing/manipulation
- 2D Games
- Advanced image viewing such as [Microsoft's Deep Zoom](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/DeepZoom/Default.html)

If you can't understand how it's beneficial, then maybe it isn't from your point of view at least. Don't think that because it's there I have to use it somehow, pick and choose what technologies work for you based on what you're trying to build, an Accounting web app probably wouldn't need a canvas for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The canvas will enable you to draw pixel perfect graphics.

Answer (score 0):

The cool projects that came to mind for me are:

- Visualize gps data. GPS data is just an XML list of coordinates. You could easily build something in canvas to "connect the dots".
- An mobile app where the user can actual sign a document with her finger - canvas allows you to export out the rendered canvas drawing to PNG where it can be saved on the server.
- In a game where you have avatars, you can allow the user to actual draw on the avatar. Moustaches anyone?

Other stuff:

- In iOS / Android using lots of CSS3
  effects like box-shadow can lead to
  poor performance, especially when
  animating. You can do a lot of these
  graphics in a single canvas tag,
  here's an example:
  http://everytimezone.com/. This thing is flawless on an ipad.
- Cool background effects. For example try going to Paul Irish's
  site and move your cursor around the
  background: http://paulirish.com/
- In this HTML5 book sponsored by Google a lot of the effects are using
  canvas:
  http://www.20thingsilearned.com/ -
  particularly the "page flip"
  animations.

Answer (score 0):

my personal take on canvas (and when I actually found a use case for canvas) is the ability to color pick and color change per pixel in a canvas element - actually moving the image from something we don't have any information about what is happening inside it to an element like all other DOM elements (and yes, I know about the current problems with canvas and DOM - sure this would be taken care of in the future)

sure - canvas made some sort of animation easier and pluginless, but that we could do before (mostly with flash) - I think the real importance is the ability to know what is happening on the page.